# Message sent to deallocated instance - NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I've got a strange issue.  This is suddenly started happening in the code that used to work with no problem.

I have a simple code like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:viewControllersList forKey:kViewControllersKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Where I'm saving some info into the UserDefaults (for state preservation).

All of a sudden today on the first line of this code I started receiving

```
*** -[CFDictionary isNSDictionary__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x65bc5d0
```

It happens almost always, but not quite.  If I delete the app from the simulator, clean the project and rebuild/run, then it works.  If I stop the app and re-start - the error is back.

I'm totally stuck at this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ar trying to add a `NSDictionary` (`viewControllersList`) but this `NSDictionary` is already released

Comment: No, `viewControllersList` is not a dictionary - it's an array

Comment: Ok, turns out, one of the elements in the array that I was setting was an NSMutableDiectionary, which is getting deallocated somewhere somehow.  I still need to track that down, but at least I'm past this problem.